# apt-get update fails for missing GPG keys but keys are present

Tags: apt

I am trying to run apt-get update on a newly upgraded to 16.04 machine. 
It complains about missing keys. But when I query apt-key it shows the keys as present. I have tried removing the keys and getting them again but I still get the errors.

Here is the output of apt-get update:

```
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5  NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
```

trimmed to remove what looked like excessive links to avoid the 
"You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links." message

And here is the output of apt-key list:

```
# apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

I have even tried taking the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg file from this machine and moved it to another machine and it works fine there.

ETA:
The /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was the permissions on the /etc/apt directory.
Somehow it got set to 700 . On working machines it was 755. When I changed it to 755 on my newly upgraded machine it worked fine.